# How to set camera orientation in Android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, screen-orientation, exif

I've looked at other questions where people have asked this, but I wasn't sure what the best way to solve this problem was. After going through Android's guide to implement the camera, the camera preview I have is locked into landscape. I wanted to know how to adjust the camera orientation to mirror the orientation of the phone.

I tried this

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

And that locked the camera into portrait mode, so I need another solution (preferably one that works for most devices).

Also, how can I make it so the saved image shows up the same way as the preview? Right now if I use that line of code above to make the preview go to portrait, the saved image is still rotated for a landscape.

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn, I'll withdraw the vote. I was editing the title of the other one, and only a minor wording tweak gave an exact title duplicate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Camera.Parameters params= mCamera.getParameters();
 params.set("rotation", 90); 
 mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: That didn't do anything for me

Comment: you have to use  params.set("rotation", 90);  insted of setDisplayOrientation

Comment: Yup, I did that. It didn't do anything while setDisplayOrientation had done something.

Comment: then mostly you are setting any configuration in other ways. please check the custom camera class

Comment: Sorry, that did fix the problem of the saved image not being in the same orientation as the preview. To fix the preview, I used this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)

Comment: I would suggest instead of hard coding the `90` to use `android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();  
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraId, info);   
        mSensorOrientation = info.orientation;` to get the right sensor orientation from the camera itself and then use it in the `params.set(mSensorOrientation)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the orientation into account when determining what preview size to choose. For example, the `getOptimalPreviewSize()` from the `CameraPreview` of ApiDemos is oblivious to orientation, simply because their version of that app has the orientation locked to landscape. If you wish to let the orientation float, you need to reverse the target aspect ratio to match. So, where `getOptimalPreviewSize()` has this

```
double targetRatio=(double)width / height;
```

And

```
if (displayOrientation == 90 || displayOrientation == 270) {
  targetRatio=(double)height / width;
}
```

where `displayOrientation` is a value from 0 to 360, that I am determining from about 100 lines of some seriously ugly code, which is why I am wrapping all of this up in a reusable component that I'll publish shortly.

Second, you need to take that display orientation into account when controlling the aspect ratio of the `SurfaceView`/`TextureView` that you are using. The `CameraPreview` activity from `ApiDemos` has its own Preview `ViewGroup` that handles the aspect ratio, and there you need to reverse the aspect ratio for use in portrait:

```
if (displayOrientation == 90
        || displayOrientation == 270) {
      previewWidth=mPreviewSize.height;
      previewHeight=mPreviewSize.width;
    }
    else {
      previewWidth=mPreviewSize.width;
      previewHeight=mPreviewSize.height;
    }
```

where `displayOrientation` is that same value (90 and 270 being portrait and reverse-portrait respectively, and note that I haven't tried getting reverse-portrait or reverse-landscape to work, so there may be more tweaking required).

Third - you must start the preview before calling `setPictureSize()` on the `Camera.Parameters`. Otherwise, it's as if the aspect ratio of the picture is applied to the preview frames, screwing things up.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
Camera.Size pictureSize=getHost().getPictureSize(parameters);

parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();

parameters=camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: Where are you finding this method getOptimalPreviewSize()?

Comment: private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {….}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using the Google's camera app. It gets the phone's orientation by using a sensor and then sets the EXIF tag appropriately. The JPEG which comes out of the camera is not oriented automatically.

Also, the camera preview works properly only in the landscape mode. If you need your activity layout to be oriented in portrait, you will have to do it manually using the value from the orientation sensor.

I'd recommend checking the photo's exif data and looking particularly for

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(SourceFileName);   //API Level 5
String exifOrientation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

Leave comment and Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I don't want to use an external app for this.

Comment: A camera preview does not have to be in landscape mode. Starting in Android 2.2 (API Level 8), you can use the setDisplayOrientation() method to set the rotation of the preview image. In order to change preview orientation as the user re-orients the phone, within the surfaceChanged() method of your preview class, first stop the preview with Camera.stopPreview() change the orientation and then start the preview again with Camera.startPreview().

Comment: you can also check more on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29

Comment: Yes I've read that but how do I know how much to rotate it by, and how to recognize when it's in landscape or portrait.

Comment: the getOptimalPreviewSize() from the CameraPreview of ApiDemos is oblivious to orientation, simply because their version of that app has the orientation locked to landscape. If you wish to let the orientation float, you need to reverse the target aspect ratio to match.